# Adversarial Indistinguishability

Tags: symmetric

I am trying to devise an encryption scheme such that an adversary can win the following game with probability at most $1/2 + \epsilon$.

- Adversary gives challenger two plaintext messages $m_1$ and $m_0$
- Challenger chooses one the two at random and encrypts it and gives adversary the cipher
- Adversary determines which of the two messages was chosen.

The key space has to be smaller than the message space.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want to know ciphers that are vulnerable to this attack. There may be an infinite amount of ciphers that fit this description. Is it really what you're asking? If so, then this is not a good question for any site.

Comment: The others misunderstood the question. You want something that is secure under this. In any case, this is a really really basic question. You should read about secure encryption and you'll find the answer.

Comment: This is (mostly) achieved by any semantically secure encryption system; lots of systems are believed to meet these requirements.  Note that you have to be a bit careful when it comes to the permitted lengths of $m_0$ and $m_1$; if $m_0$ is 1 bit, and $m_1$ is a Petabyte long, most systems would output ciphertexts of detectably differing lengths.  We typically deal with this by insisting that $m_0$ and $m_1$ be the same length (in which case, you can eliminate the "(mostly)" qualifier from my first sentence)

Comment: What you're asking for is a scheme that is secure against eavesdroppers (EAV-secure). What assumptions are you willing to make?

Answer (score 1):

An adversary can easily win this game with $\epsilon = 0.5$ when the scheme under examination is any block cipher in ECB mode.

Simply set $m_0$ and $m_1$ to the same block value, $q$. This guarantees that you'll get the encryption of $q$ back, which we'll call $r$.

Then you can distinguish between $q$ and some other block value with probability $1$ on subsequent trial by checking whether $r$ is returned or not.